# Can I bind a hotkey to a spanish character?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm looking to use a hotkey to type specific Spanish letters, like <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> outputting ñ. However, I don't want to use the dead keys thing, and the compose key doesn't give me the ñ character as far as I can tell. I know how to make hotkeys, just not the command to type. (Much less type characters that aren't on my keyboard or keyboard layout.)

Comment: you probably want to configure XKB options properly (so Compose or AltGr work as expected) rather than to configure this by a random hotkey.  see `/etc/default/keyboard`.  if you're on a typical US layout, you'll probably want the `altgr-intl` layout (deadkeys only activate with AltGr but normal otherwise).  the XKB option `lv3:lalt_switch` would put AltGr on your left Alt instead of the default right Alt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a US or UK keyboard (and possibly others but I don't know) you can go to System Settings -> Text Entry, and add a keyboard with “international with AltGr dead keys” or “alternative international” in the name (which name it lists depends on the Ubuntu version as far as I can tell). With this your right Alt gives you áéíóúüñ¿¡ and even ç (and a bunch more useful ones), and a number of dead keys. As long as you don't press that key it's your regular US (or UK) keyboard; press that key and it changes mode. I mostly write in English but I often write in Spanish and this is the only layout that is unobtrusive enough that I don't need to release muscle memory, while still being quick and obvious to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can type this character in using: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>U</kbd> then type `00f1` and press enter.

Also we can use `xdotool` to bind a key for this character, if `xdotool` is not installed first install it (around 60kb) using:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Go into keyboard settings, add a custom keyboard shortcut with this content:

```
sh -c "xdotool type ñ"
```

The best result I got was binding a <kbd>Fx</kbd> key.

[image]